# Do the Sharingan dots decide their power/ family tree?

Tags: naruto

In chapter 674 page 9, Madara says that Sasuke is the only one who awakened a Sharingan with straight commas, just like his. After that, he says that there might be a connection between them, something beyond blood.

[image]
[image]

Does this mean that an Uchiha can be distinguished by their Sharingan? Does this also mean that the power of their eye is decided by the type of commas (tomoe) they have?

Comment: i beleive we have to wait for successive chaptors as no clear evidence are currently present which could highlight different power/family tree based on sharingan commas or tamoes.

Comment: We do know one thing for sure. The more tomoe (commas) an Uchiha has, the stronger he is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what Madara means by "straight commas" is that Sasuke awakened the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan just like he did. No one in the Naruto series has been shown to possess Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan(s) besides these two, so that must be what he meant.

As for the average Sharingan, 3 commas is the mastered form. However, Kakashi, Obito, Itachi, Sasuke and a handful of other Uchihas have been shown to have those 3 commas in their regular Sharingan. Also, all the Sharingan(s) embedded in Danzo's arm had three commas. So for Madara to say that Sasuke is the only one who awakened a Sharingan with straight commas like him, he couldn't be pertaining to the regular Sharingan, but the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan.

Answer (score 4):

Could be because they're both the reincarnations of the Sage's son of this and the previous generations why their Sharingan have straight lines. Itachi and Sasuke are brothers and their Mangekyo looked nothing alike

Answer (score 1):

I think the statement does have something to do with the Eternal Mangekyo, but it's not the only reason. If you look at Sasuke and Madara's Eternal Mangekyo, they are the only ones with straight lines (straight commas) within them. I think that is what they are talking about, as their normal Sharingan has normal commas.

Answer (score -1):

The straight tomoe that they are referring to is the straight whole lines concept and pattern that sasuke and madara had after awakening their regular mangekyou. The black in the red of their sharingan shows their advanced range of perception or (power) compared to a normal eyed person. In a sense every black part is their pupil,red is their iris. The red is What allows them to see chakra since it would shade the pupil or the black tomoe differently and allow them to see things the way they do.

Comment: Could you cite your sources on this?